# Understanding different coordinate systems, Tiled, Stage, Screen,

Tags: java, libgdx, coordinates

I am very confused about all the different coordinate systems.
I am using LibGDX with Tiled.
These all have their own coordinate system (sortof).

- LibGDX screen
- Tiled map
- UIcamera
- Orthogonal TiledMapCamera
- UIStage
- TiledMapStage

It's too many concepts and I can no longer mentally understand how they affect each other in complex scenarios, like

- having different screen dimensions than the tiled map dimensions
- when resizing the screen.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a 2D game, you really only have to think about the coordinate system of the orthographic camera. Whatever is drawn with a certain camera's `combined` matrix is fit to the rectangle of the screen (and if you set up the camera correctly, it will not be distorted).

LibGDX provides the Viewport classes for helping to set up your camera. You can think of them as camera managers that will size the camera to meet the arrangement you want. You instantiate them with a desired size "window" you want to see of the game world. And the only place you have to consider the actual screen dimensions is in the `resize` method, where you pass the dimensions to the Viewport class and let it handle sizing your camera for you so the scene won't be distorted.

You might have more than one camera. Typically your UI will have its own, and the gameplay world will have another (because you want it to move around in the world).

When it comes to input, the raw X and Y are given in screen pixel coordinates, but you just pass these coordinates to the `camera.unproject` method to have them converted to the same coordinates as your game world.

I don't use tiles, so I can't get specific there, but the same principles should apply.